# Dealing with precise units in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

Does anyone have experience with / can anyone suggest best practices for storing quantities with large variants in magnitude?

For example, an attribute in one of my models is used to store a weight that could be anything from a few micrograms up to a kilogram or more. My assumption is to convert everything to the smallest unit and store it in the database as an integer (since I might lose accuracy with a float?), but it seems weird to be storing kilogram quantities in micrograms..

Is anybody able to suggest a ruby/rails plugin that might help with this kind of behavior, in the more generic sense? In the same way that a 'time' field in a database is converted into a `Time` object in ruby, how would I go about best intercepting the `database entry -> class attribute` process, converting a field into my class of choice?

Is there a design pattern for storing varying unit magnitudes that I'm just not thinking of?

Comment: This is a Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498394/milliseconds-with-rails-and-mysql

Comment: Similar, perhaps, but not a duplicate. When I first searched for answers before posting, your link was not a match; It focuses on time, whereas I'm more interested in a pattern for the general case, which I think Phrogz has answered well.

Comment: As I answered, the pattern for the general case is to use rails aggregations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If precision is important, then what you propose is a good idea. Whether with currency or weights, store the integer amount of the smallest unit you can measure.

Alternatively, use [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html), which provides support for arbitrary precision (as in you-get-to-choose-the-precision, not as in Ruby-randomly-chooses-it). Good support for storing this depends on your database—for example, PostgreSQL provides the [`NUMERIC` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) precisely for this purpose—and requires support from your ORM (presumably ActiveRecord, which supports this in migrations through the `:decimal` column type).

Even though money typically varies by orders of magnitude smaller than the difference between micrograms to kilograms, you will not run into any problems if you [handle this like money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money) and just set your precision appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Time issue: You don't need a rails plugin for this. You have Rails aggregations for this purpose:

[Milliseconds with Rails and Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498394/milliseconds-with-rails-and-mysql) (Is your question an intentional duplicate of this one?!)

As for the precision. That's just a matter of using the best type available in the DBMS.